# Resolve many-to-one, child before parent table problem

Tags: mysql, database-design, many-to-one

In my program, I need to make an organization chart starting with individuals and grouping them under a manager, then group those managers under senior managers etc... How do I do this with regards to the database?? This is a many to one relationship - which I thought was illegal and impossible - and would be like starting with the child table - individuals - before creating its parent - manager.
If someone can help point me in the right direction to design my database I'd really appreciate it!!

----***EDIT***----
Here's a more detailed explanation of my problem:

Let's say a user of my program starts by entering in 35 individuals they'd like to use on some project they're going to work on. Now, there are several possible management positions that can be created and have employees/other (lower) managers assigned to those. The user doesn't HAVE TO create any particular position, but can pick and choose and assign however they like. The only constraints are there will always be a top manager - let's call him the President - and that he SHOULD (but doesn't HAVE TO) only assign 5-10 people to any given manager (president included). So in this example we are starting with 35 individuals and a President. Now we start grouping the 35 individuals into teams and assigning one of them as manager. Say the user decides to have two teams of 6, two teams of 9, and one team of 5 - each of these groups has one of its individual members assigned as manager of that team. So now we have 5 teams, each under its own manager, and those five managers would now be assigned to the President. The program would let this go but warn the user that the number of individuals under a manager in the last team is less than 5 (is only 4). So the user can now (or at ANYtime) go back and change the organization. So let's say he wants to fix this issue and changes up the teams. So he breaks up one of the two teams of 9 and assigns one individual to the team that was short a person. This makes a final count of 3 teams of 6 (5 individual members and one manager), one team of 9 (8 ind and 1 mngr), and one team of 8 (7 ind and 1 mngr) and all 5 team managers are assigned to the president.

Only in real life this can get broken down much further - nests with many more levels of management. How can I do this?

Is Joe Hopfgartner's answer below still valid? Can I just make a "role" column, even though the role would be assigned later (after the row is initially created)? Or changed at any time? Can this self-referencing foreign key be null? (as it would be in the case that no manager has been assigned yet) Or should I move the individuals to a separate "team" table after they've been assigned to a team and move the managers to a "manager" table once they've been assigned as a manager, then add a foreign key for the team table referencing the manager table?

Also, I am using MySQL, so does that fact that you cannot use self-referential ON UPDATE CASCADE or ON UPDATE SET NULL operations affect my particular case (since users will no doubt often be changing the assignments)?

Thank you so much for helping me with this!!!

Comment: Why would many-to-one relationships be "illegal and impossible"?

Comment: how do you use foreign keys in a many-to-one relationship?

Comment: You just use a non-unique index. Suppose table `employees` has `id` and `manager_id` columns, where `id` is the primary key and `manager_id` can be NULL and is defined with an INDEX. Then you can do this: `ALTER TABLE manager ADD FOREIGN KEY (manager_id) REFERENCES employees(id) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE`. The table should be defined to use the InnoDB engine for the constraints to work. Note that the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) explicitly says: _The foreign key can be self referential (referring to the same table)._

Comment: Yes, in MySQL the foreign key can be self referential (and I know to use InnoDB, it's the only MySQL engine that supports foreign keys), but the manual ALSO explicitly says: "Deviation from SQL standards: If ON UPDATE CASCADE or ON UPDATE SET NULL recurses to update the same table it has previously updated during the cascade, it acts like RESTRICT. This means that you cannot use self-referential ON UPDATE CASCADE  or ON UPDATE SET NULL operations." Therefore I couldn't do ON UPDATE CASCADE as per your suggestion. (ON DELETE SET NULL is fine though)

Comment: Unless you have another foreign key constraing in the same table that references the `manager_id` column, then there won't be any recursive cascade from ON UPDATE CASCADE and there won't be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if one individual can only have one manager, just introduce a "parent person" id field or put managers in a seperate table.

if not, create another table for a relation like "person_has_manager" that assigns a person to a manager.

you can also put managers and persons into the same table and introduce a "role" field, but this can be tricky when using foreign key constraints if you want to ensure that only manages can have persons assigned to them.

to solve this problem you can introduce a "person_is_manager" table that links person to their  job as manager, and persons can be linked to be managed by that manager. this ould look like this:

```
persons
-> person_id (primary)
-> name
-> etc

managers
-> person_id (primary, linked to person_id in persons)

person_has_manager
-> person_id (primary)
-> manager_id (primary, linked to person_id in managers table)
```

Comment: "this can be tricky when using foreign key constraints if you want to ensure that only managers can have persons assigned to them"     Well, a person can be a manager and be assigned to a manager also... Does that matter? I think, at any rate, I'd rather not use a "role" field in the same table. But all the individuals will be in the same table. So do I have to go that route then? Or can I move the person to the managers table once he has been assigned as a manager and then link his subordinates to him? And then link him to his manager as well?

Comment: the last structure that is also ligned out should satisfy all your needs. all persons are defined in the persons table, a corresponding entry in the managers table gives them the manager attribute. now any person, including managers, can be assigned to any number of managers, but only if they are managers.

Comment: All individuals will be assigned to a "team" before a manager is assigned, so perhaps I should have a "team" table 1st, person_id (primary, linked to person_id in persons) and then a managers table, THEN a person has manager table?  THANKS!!!!

Comment: sure thats also possible! probably a good idea too, because you can link future entities to the team.

Comment: there are always a lot of possible strucutres. which are best is often a question of style and/or not definite without the knowledge of future developements and the kind of database queries that will be applied. just keep the following in mind: in a good database structure the changing / deleting / inserting of ONE must not make the data inconsistent. avoiding redundandancy is the most important thing.

Comment: Right, thanks. That's what I'm trying to avoid by making sure I'm "wrapping my head around" the problem right - by setting up these tables with foreign keys I am ensuring referential integrity right? And speaking of database queries that will be applied... I am having MUCH difficulty there, as the tables will be created, inserted into and updated by means of an organization chart. That's how this must all be sorted out.

Comment: The user will first enter in all the employees' info, then by means of some interactive tool I need to make/find (can't find any/get google's vis orgchart to be dynamically editable...?) the user will drag and drop or select/click "add" button and group all employees into teams and assign managers within this orgchart tool, then be added to database too...... Anyway you can help me with ideas about how to allow users to make such an org chart, or something like this that already exists that I can use? THANKS!!!! You're so very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

It's a tree. You can use a single table with a `parent_id` field, to indicate which record is the parent to the current one.

Comment: I understand that if I had the parent table first I could indicate which record is the parent record, but that is exactly my problem. I have the child(ren) table(s) first and then must create the parent table after, and then link them. How can I do this... it's impossible. So ho do I work around it?